# Negative margin-left to hide left side of element

Tags: styles, margins

I need to use a left negative margin so that my element left side would disappear on the left side of the screen.

I tried using position relative but it doesn't work...

```
<div class="card" id="historyCard">
  <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
    <h5 class="mb-0">
      <button class="btn btn-link" id="historyBtn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        היסטוריה
         <img src="images/clock.png" id="hamNavHistoryImg" width="87" height="87"/>
      </button>
    </h5>
  </div></div>

        #historyCard {
        background-color: #ffb59b;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
        border-top-right-radius: 50%;
        padding: 30px 0 80px 0;
        margin-top: 10px;
        z-index: 5;
        margin-left:-50px;
    }
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A44hg.png)

Comment: Can you add your codes?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question.

Comment: In your code, which one has "historyCard" id?

Comment: Please add your full code.

Comment: It's an accordion. I added the first tab only, is there anything else in the code that you need me to add?

Comment: You must find it by debugging.